# Hot to set line height in Sublime Text tab set control

Tags: sublimetext3

I want to change the font size for a larger, but I can't change the line height, so that  letters like g p q are "under cropped"

I haven't found solutions, seems than nobody has changed the labels line height on "tab set control" ¿?

I tried

```
"row_padding": [8, 3],  // increase second value e.g. [8, 6]
"indent": 12,
```

and

```
"line_padding_bottom": 3,
"line_padding_top": 3
```

without success

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug, with currently no workarounds (as at build 3126): https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/694

EDIT: this has been fixed in build 3127.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I needed to know I was not falling fool